# Google Analytics and visited links CSS

Tags: javascript, css, google-analytics

I have 4 sites linked to each other and tracked by GA method:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(...)"
```

This will result in GA parameter with random value in URL, for example:

```
http://example.com/great-page/?_ga=1.78527441.491437166.1409121868
```

But I want to have every visited link styled with CSS:

```
a:visited {color: purple}
```

But it will not be properly styled thanks to the random GA parametre in the URL, that is always different.

**Any ideas how to style visited links with GA params in URL?**

Comment: What does the HTML for one of the links that's *not* being highlighted look like?

Comment: HTML of the links is very simple - just href and onclick attributes. They are not being properly highlighted thanks to everytime different value of GA parameter in URL

Comment: I don't know, but you could add `a[href*="_ga="] { color: purple; }` to style all GA links purple if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already generated a canonical URL for each page. If not, the canonical URL is what URL the current page is suppose to have.

On each page, add the following Javascript code:

```
history.pushState({id:1},document.title,CANONICAL)
```

This changes the URL displayed to the user without reloading the page.

For example, if you're using PHP, it'll be something like:

```
history.pushState({id:1},document.title,"<?php echo get_canonical() ?>")
```

This will add the canonical URL to the browser's history. Then, for each link, set the `href` attribute to the canonical URL.

This has the added benefit of changing ugly URLs like `http://example.com/page?utm_source=blah` to `http://example.com/page` (after Google Analytics processes the `utm_source`)